# Click an item from a drop-down menu - RSelenium

Tags: web-scraping, rstudio, rselenium

Good morning everyone,

I am using Selenium to extract certain information based on my research.
I enter the word of my interest and when I go to click on the search (using clickelement ()) I get the this answer:

```
Class method definition for method clickElement()
function () 
{
    "Click the element."
    qpath <- sprintf("%s/session/%s/element/%s/click", 
        serverURL, sessionInfo[["id"]], elementId)
    queryRD(qpath, "POST")
}
<environment: 0x000001e1ea819ac8>

Methods used: 
     "queryRD"
```

Is there anyone who can explain and help me?
I thank everyone in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to add which webdriver you're using.

Comment: webelem3 <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css","#inputheaderlg")
webelem3$sendKeysToElement(list("003-120507-01-DL"))
  
 webelem4 <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css","#headersearchformlg .ng-scope+ .ng-scope span:nth-child(1)")
 webelem4$clickElement                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
I select the search bar, enter the value ("003-120507-01-DL")
 and I get that answer

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the rstudio IDE. Please do not use that tag if you are web-scraping in R, and use the R tag instead.

Comment: You might as well tag the OS that your computer uses, the desk that your computer is sitting on, or the room that it's in. If you use `RSelenium` you are using R. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html

Comment: Moreover, the Rstudio tag is rarely used by the community to answer questions, while the R tag is heavily frequented. I'm trying to help you in ensuring that you get the help you need. I also don't know what you mean by "needing points". Helping you doesn't give me anything.

Comment: @StefanoMariaDeFrancesco if you use RStudio without using R, you might have bigger problems. R is the programming language and the interpreter that you use. RStudio might be the IDE you use, but it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Please take the time to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and check out the answers to [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If you want to add any info, update the question; don't hide it in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, for your clarifications, for your corrections. But let's go back to my problem, do you have a solution?